# C# regular expression for /" at end of string

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, double-quotes

I have a collection of url's and i need to write regular expression to filter needed content.

> /data/43492-someText/"
>
> /data/221639-anotherText/"
>
> /data/116345-differentText/"
>
> /data/6630-boooring/"
>
> /data/220742-foo/"

What i need is only strings without /" on the end, so

> /data/220742-foo

My Regular Expression looks like this:

```
@"/data/[0-9]{1,10}-.*""\s"
```

Note: I dont want to do this with string replace, because of some limitations on my project.

Comment: How about `String.Split('/')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Regular Expressions are kind of overkill for what you're trying to do.

Anyways you can use something like [this](http://regexr.com?32s1k):

```
@"/data/[0-9]{1,10}-[^/]+"
```

Answer (score 5):

If that (string not ending in `/`) is the only requirement, then use something like this:

```
var desiredUrls = urls.Where(url => !url.EndsWith("/\""))
```

I initially read the question as a desire to filter urls but I can see how it could be a mapping question.

```
var withoutSuffix = urls.Select(url => url.TrimEnd("/\"".ToCharArray());
```

Comment: The example used in the question hints at mapping, not filtering.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) to remove the characters from the end of a string:

```
s.TrimEnd('/', '"')
```

Comment: That will trim / and/or ". Not /". Of course, that might be fine with the OP... I'm just nitpicking.

Comment: I know it would technically do more than that. But if the input is actually a bunch of URIs then there won't be an arbitrary string of `/` and `"`  at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
(/data/[0-9]{1,10}-.+)/
```

And the string without the trailing / will be in the first capture group.